# How to handle both event click and long pressed on gridview android?

Tags: android, gridview, click, long-press

My app requirement is handle both click event and long pressed event on grid view.

I have try both but not working only long pressed event work.

if i remove long pressed event then click event working.

But when i am try to put both event then only long pressed event work.

so how can i implement both event on grid view android.

i have search lots of thing but not getting perfect solution any one have solution or idea then help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Code :-

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
    onGridItemClick(v,pos,id);
}
});

protected void onGridItemClick(View v, int pos, long id) {
Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick id=" + id);
}

gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
    return onLongGridItemClick(v,pos,id);
}
});

protected boolean onLongGridItemClick(View v, int pos, long id) {
Log.i(TAG, "onLongGridItemClick id=" + id);
return true;
}
```

Comment: return true will be prevent click event to be continued. It will then perform only OnItemLongClickListener..

Comment: i have try return false but not working

Comment: I used your code in a dummy project I created and it seems to work fine. The problem is somewhere else. May be in the xml.

Comment: in gridview adapter have one imageview and textview, so any tag add in imageview or textview

Comment: rakex thnxs for try my code ites working fine now, i find some silly mistake in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should return false in your long click listener. This way event is not consumed and passed on to item click listener.

```
protected boolean onLongGridItemClick(View v, int pos, long id) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLongGridItemClick id=" + id);
    return false;
}
```